# React: Generate all date of birth select options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

At the moment I've got a load of HTML in my script and its ugly to scroll past, is there a way I can generate all the options from 2019 to 1900 and then just loop over them?

````
            <select
              className='form--dob-year'
              name='year'
              onChange={onChange}
              value={year}
            >
              <option value='0'>Year</option>
              <option value='2019'>2019</option>
              <option value='2018'>2018</option>
              <option value='2017'>2017</option>
              <option value='2016'>2016</option>
              <option value='2015'>2015</option>
              <option value='2014'>2014</option>
              <option value='2013'>2013</option>
              <option value='2012'>2012</option>
              <option value='2011'>2011</option>
              <option value='2010'>2010</option>
              <option value='2009'>2009</option>
              <option value='2008'>2008</option>
              <option value='2007'>2007</option>
              <option value='2006'>2006</option>
              <option value='2005'>2005</option>
              <option value='2004'>2004</option>
              <option value='2003'>2003</option>
              <option value='2002'>2002</option>
              <option value='2001'>2001</option>
              <option value='2000'>2000</option>
              <option value='1999'>1999</option>
              <option value='1998'>1998</option>
              <option value='1997'>1997</option>
              <option value='1996'>1996</option>
              <option value='1995'>1995</option>
              <option value='1994'>1994</option>
              <option value='1993'>1993</option>
              <option value='1992'>1992</option>
              <option value='1991'>1991</option>
              <option value='1990'>1990</option>
              <option value='1989'>1989</option>
              <option value='1988'>1988</option>
              <option value='1987'>1987</option>
              <option value='1986'>1986</option>
              <option value='1985'>1985</option>
              <option value='1984'>1984</option>
              <option value='1983'>1983</option>
              <option value='1982'>1982</option>
              <option value='1981'>1981</option>
              <option value='1980'>1980</option>
              <option value='1979'>1979</option>
              <option value='1978'>1978</option>
              <option value='1977'>1977</option>
              <option value='1976'>1976</option>
              <option value='1975'>1975</option>
              <option value='1974'>1974</option>
              <option value='1973'>1973</option>
              <option value='1972'>1972</option>
              <option value='1971'>1971</option>
              <option value='1970'>1970</option>
              <option value='1969'>1969</option>
              <option value='1968'>1968</option>
              <option value='1967'>1967</option>
              <option value='1966'>1966</option>
              <option value='1965'>1965</option>
              <option value='1964'>1964</option>
              <option value='1963'>1963</option>
              <option value='1962'>1962</option>
              <option value='1961'>1961</option>
              <option value='1960'>1960</option>
              <option value='1959'>1959</option>
              <option value='1958'>1958</option>
              <option value='1957'>1957</option>
              <option value='1956'>1956</option>
              <option value='1955'>1955</option>
              <option value='1954'>1954</option>
              <option value='1953'>1953</option>
              <option value='1952'>1952</option>
              <option value='1951'>1951</option>
              <option value='1950'>1950</option>
              <option value='1949'>1949</option>
              <option value='1948'>1948</option>
              <option value='1947'>1947</option>
              <option value='1946'>1946</option>
              <option value='1945'>1945</option>
              <option value='1944'>1944</option>
              <option value='1943'>1943</option>
              <option value='1942'>1942</option>
              <option value='1941'>1941</option>
              <option value='1940'>1940</option>
              <option value='1939'>1939</option>
              <option value='1938'>1938</option>
              <option value='1937'>1937</option>
              <option value='1936'>1936</option>
              <option value='1935'>1935</option>
              <option value='1934'>1934</option>
              <option value='1933'>1933</option>
              <option value='1932'>1932</option>
              <option value='1931'>1931</option>
              <option value='1930'>1930</option>
              <option value='1929'>1929</option>
              <option value='1928'>1928</option>
              <option value='1927'>1927</option>
              <option value='1926'>1926</option>
              <option value='1925'>1925</option>
              <option value='1924'>1924</option>
              <option value='1923'>1923</option>
              <option value='1922'>1922</option>
              <option value='1921'>1921</option>
              <option value='1920'>1920</option>
              <option value='1919'>1919</option>
              <option value='1918'>1918</option>
              <option value='1917'>1917</option>
              <option value='1916'>1916</option>
              <option value='1915'>1915</option>
              <option value='1914'>1914</option>
              <option value='1913'>1913</option>
              <option value='1912'>1912</option>
              <option value='1911'>1911</option>
              <option value='1910'>1910</option>
              <option value='1909'>1909</option>
              <option value='1908'>1908</option>
              <option value='1907'>1907</option>
              <option value='1906'>1906</option>
              <option value='1905'>1905</option>
              <option value='1904'>1904</option>
              <option value='1903'>1903</option>
              <option value='1902'>1902</option>
              <option value='1901'>1901</option>
              <option value='1900'>1900</option>
            </select>
    ```
````

Comment: Why not just let them type the year? With a massive list of options, the older someone is, the more they have to scroll and the less tolerant they are likely to be for having to scroll all the way to their year of birth. Why punish oldies? Would you like to scroll over say 50 options or just type "1961"? Or just let them put in their age.

Comment: good question maybe its to remove user error, give the oldies a box where any 4 numbers can be entered and we will get results like 8888 maybe?

Comment: Oh yeah, oldies love to type random numbers but given 120 options they'll pick the right one every time… :-/

Comment: Rob it's a fair argument, is there any data to suggest one way over the other is better?

Comment: Most user testing is done with the client, who is likely the worst person to test on. Just do some real testing with **real** users and see what they think. Most would much rather just type their date of birth. They're trusted to enter credit card numbers, phone numbers, drivers' licence numbers, etc. but heaven forbid they forget when they were born. ;-)

Comment: I wonder how we have ended up in this bad pattern, I see it all over the internet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a for loop. Create a function that returns an array of `JSX.Element`:

```
const generateYearOptions = () => {
  const arr = [];

  const startYear = 1900;
  const endYear = new Date().getFullYear();

  for (let i = endYear; i >= startYear; i--) {
    arr.push(<option value={i}>{i}</option>);
  }

  return arr;
};
```

Then in your component:

```
<select
  className='form--dob-year'
  name='year'
  onChange={onChange}
  value={year}
>
  <option value='0'>Year</option>
  {generateYearOptions()}
</select>
```